# Why do I use javascript to make the marquee effect and it will shake when it is running?

Tags: javascript, css

I have some problems with the marquee effect using JavaScript. It should stop in the middle when scrolling, but it can't stop in the middle at present, it will shake effect. How can I fix this?

I have solved the problem for a lot of time by myself, so I came up to ask everyone, thank you

```js
function slideLine(box,stf,delay,speed,h)
 {
  var slideBox = document.getElementById(box);
  var delay = delay||1000,speed = speed||20,h = h||20;
  var tid = null,pause = false;
  var s = function(){tid=setInterval(slide, speed);}
  var slide = function(){
   if(pause) return;
   slideBox.scrollTop += 1;
   if(slideBox.scrollTop%h == 0){
    clearInterval(tid);
    slideBox.appendChild(slideBox.getElementsByTagName(stf)[0]);
    slideBox.scrollTop = 0;
    setTimeout(s, delay);
   }
  }
  slideBox.onmouseover=function(){pause=true;}
  slideBox.onmouseout=function(){pause=false;}
  setTimeout(s, delay);
 }
 slideLine('ann_box','div',2000,25,20);
```

```css
.ann{
   overflow:hidden;
   height:60px;
   background-color: #ccc;
   text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="ann_box" class="ann" style="width:868px;">
  <div id="a1" class="ann">HTML</div>
  <div id="a2" class="ann">CSS</div>
  <div id="a3" class="ann">Vue</div>
  <div id="a4" class="ann">javascript</div>
</div>
```

Comment: By "shake" do you mean when it jumps from about mid-way all the way to the top? And, the effect does stop when you hover, as you have specifiied in the code. Can you clarify these things please

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply!

You are right, I hope he can roll to the middle and stop, but currently he will bounce directly from the bottom to the top and stay on it instead of staying in the middle!

I never know what went wrong~ Thank you

Comment: comment out `slidebox.scrollTop = 0` and see what happens.

Comment: I tried to annotate the code you mentioned, but the situation remains the same~
I wonder if it’s a CSS problem?

Comment: yep - Add this style to your css: `line-height: 60px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you can achieve this this css transform. But it will work , if the last parameter should be the same as the div's height in the `slideLine` function and control the speed with the fourth parameter.

#### css

```css
:root {
  --height: 60px; /* Same as last parameter in function */
}
#ann_box {
  min-width: 400px;
  height: var(--height);
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.ann {
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1; /* new line */
  /* height / 2 - 10px = transform   to define center */
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--height) / 2 - 10px));
}
```

#### javascript

```js
slideLine('ann_box', 'div', 2000, 25, 60); // The last parameter should be 60
```

```js
function slideLine(box, stf, delay, speed, h) {
  var slideBox = document.getElementById(box);
  var delay = delay || 1000,
    speed = speed || 50,
    h = h || 20;
  var tid = null,
    pause = false;
  var s = function() {
    tid = setInterval(slide, speed);
  };
  var slide = function() {
    if (pause) return;
    slideBox.scrollTop += 1;
    if (slideBox.scrollTop % h == 0) {
      clearInterval(tid);
      slideBox.appendChild(slideBox.getElementsByTagName(stf)[0]);
      // slideBox.scrollTop = 0;
      setTimeout(s, delay);
    }
  };
  slideBox.onmouseover = function() {
    pause = true;
  };
  slideBox.onmouseout = function() {
    pause = false;
  };
  setTimeout(s, delay);
}
slideLine('ann_box', 'div', 2000, 10, 60); // The last parameter should be 60
```

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: hsl(201, 27%, 10%);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
:root {
  --height: 60px; /* Same as last parameter in function */
}
#ann_box {
  min-width: 400px;
  height: var(--height);
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.ann {
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1; /* new line */
  /* height / 2 - 10px = transform   to define center */
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--height) / 2 - 10px));
}

/* height 30px = transform 5px */
/* height 40px = transform 10px */
/* height 50px = transform 15px */
/* height 60px = transform 20px */
```

```html
<div id="ann_box">
  <div id="a1" class="ann">HTML</div>
  <div id="a2" class="ann">CSS</div>
  <div id="a3" class="ann">Vue</div>
  <div id="a4" class="ann">javascript</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I would like to ask~
Can the marquee effect be able to move at the same speed, because now it seems that it will run very fast from the bottom to the middle, but the speed to the top in the middle is slow , Can the speed at which the lower part moves to the middle is also slow?

Comment: So, to fix this, you must have the last parameter in function the same as div's height. In this case is 60, if you want to set the div height 100, also must change in function last parameter to 100. Updated snippet.